# Magento 2 - Alternative use for getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl function

Tags: magento2

I am a newbie for Magento 2 module development. Have been working on Magento 1.9.x for quite a time and also used to work with `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl` function for sending request to a payment service provider.

The query is I don't find the function is still the right one / in use for **Magento 2** module. Curious to know is there any alternative without using payment actions ( **capture** and **authorize** ) to send the request.

I would be so grateful if someone helps me out of this.